# Android - Make a semi circle progress animation with two images

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, rotateanimation

I need to make an animation like this:

http://youtu.be/LC6wptkt2Wk?t=27s

To do this i have this three images:
[http://postimg.org/image/yhcs4svrz/](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2gy8y86.jpg)

> s13.postimg.org/u02s9rwvb/daily_goal_ring_blur.png      s28.postimg.org/b8iaoiga5/bg_global_blue_gradient.png

I tried making some rotate animations, but i'm not getting it.
Can anybody give me a hint ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you uploaded your images to a hosting site that don't require people to visit a cluttered tacky site overloaded with ads and visual excesses

Comment: I have just changed it